# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTSheet at com.macrorecorder.gui.tools.ExcelFile.main

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

This Java program should read .xlsx files and output the data in the console. However, when I start it, an error occurs.

Used to create this program:

1. [Adding data to ArrayList while reading data from Excel using POI Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38522931/adding-data-to-arraylist-while-reading-data-from-excel-using-poi-apache) - stackoverflow
2. [How to read excel in Java](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4G2tMDYjRQ&t=1153s) - youtube

**Main class**

```
package com.macrorecorder.gui.tools;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExcelFile excelFile = new ExcelFile();
        String path = "C:\\Users\\<username>\\Test.xlsx";

        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(path));

            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(excelFile.getSheetNames(workbook).get(0));
            excelFile.read(workbook, sheet);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void read(XSSFWorkbook workbook, XSSFSheet sheet) {
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getSheetNames(XSSFWorkbook workbook) {
        ArrayList<String> sheetNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            sheetNames.add(workbook.getSheetName(i));
            System.out.println(workbook.getNumberOfSheets());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Maven Dependencies** - Resource: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/4.1.2

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTSheet
    at com.<package>.gui.tools.ExcelFile.main(ExcelFile.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheet
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 1 more
```

How to avoid the above exception?

Answer (score 1):

I run your code by fixing some line of getSheetNames() and main() and the result/output is OK.

For the getSheetNames() method, I think you need to return the list of sheet name instead of null.

```
public ArrayList<String> getSheetNames(XSSFWorkbook workbook) {
    ArrayList<String> sheetNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
        sheetNames.add(workbook.getSheetName(i));
    }
    return sheetNames;
}
```

And for the main() I think you should loop over the result of getSheetNames() to get the sheet and take it to read method for printing the content.

```
ArrayList<String> sheetNames = excelFile.getSheetNames(workbook);
for (String sheetName : sheetNames) {
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
    excelFile.read(workbook, sheet);
}
```

And I change the cellType(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell) of switch case as follows...

```
switch (cell.getCellType()) {
   case NUMERIC:
        ...
   case STRING:
        ...
}
```